# Change color of element inside PNG Image loaded in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am loading a PNG image into a UIImageView and I want to change the color of the blue circle to other colors programmatically when I press only inside of the circle. I don't want to reload the image every single time when I choose different color. Is it possible way to change the color only on the circle not the background?

And I don't want to use UIBezierPath because the PNG image maybe contains some other vector graphic shapes or contours. Thanks :)

[image: PNG image with transparent background]